# Reducing the range of a hash function maintaining even distribution

Tags: c, hash, cron

I'm writing a cron-like job-dispatcher that runs jobs every minute (and other jobs every 5 minutes, etc.). However, instead of immediately dispatching all the jobs that run on a particular period at the top-of-the-minute, I want to spawn them evenly over their periods.

For example, if I have N jobs that run every P minutes, rather than spawn them all at P:00, I want to spawn the jobs evenly over the P*60 seconds, i.e., `ceil(N/P*60)` jobs per second.  Hence, the spawn time for each job would be "skewed" somewhat later.

However, for each job J, I want J to be spawned at the *same* skew every time it's dispatched so that the time between spawns for J is constant (and matches its period).

Each job has various information associated with it, including several strings that vary for each job. My original thought was to calculate a hash-code, H, for one or more of the strings and mod it by P*60 to calculate a constant skew, S, for each job. As long as the strings associated with the job remain the same, the calculated skew would remain constant.

However, I would assume that `S=H%(P*60)` suffers from  to [problems similar to using `rand()`](http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/random.html) (uneven distribution that's biased towards lower numbers). However, I don't think the solutions presented there (to call `rand()` multiple times) would apply to my case where I'm using a hash-code because the hash function for a given job would always return the same hash.

So how can I get what I want?  (I'm writing in C.)

---

## Examples:

1. Suppose I have N every-minute jobs (a cron schedule of `* * * * *`). For N < 60 (let's say 2), then job-1 might be skewed to start at :23 (23 seconds past the minute) and job-2 might be skewed to start at :37. With so few jobs, it may not seem evenly distributed. However, as N approached 60, the "gaps" would fill in (assuming a perfect skew function) so that one job would be spawned every second. If N passed 60, some jobs spawned at some seconds would "double up." Similarly, as N approached 120, the "gaps" would again fill in so that two jobs would be spawned every second. And so on.
2. Supppose I have N every-five-minute jobs (a cron schedule of `*/5 * * * *`). In "normal" cron, that means "every five minutes on the zeroth second on the fives." I *instead* want that to mean "every five minutes, but not necessarily (and most likely not) on the zeroth second of *some* minute, but the only guarantee is that the interval between spawns will be five minutes." So for example, a particular job might be spawned at 00:07:24, 00:12:24, 00:17:24, etc. As N approached 300, one job would be spawned per second.

Comment: I would offset the task with `reverse_bit_pattern(P)%59 + 1`.  Use 59 as it is a nice prime and sacrifice starting anything at 0.

Comment: @chux Can you explain why that supposedly yields a uniform distribution, i.e., is not biased towards small numbers? And where are H and S in your equation?

Comment: @chux Also, that will yield numbers in the range [1,59] which isn't what I want. I want numbers in the range [0,P*60] where P can be _any_ number of minutes >= 1.

Comment: What on earth does the length of the strings have to do with anything? Yes H%(P*60) is biased, anything that isn't a power of 2 in the mod will bias it, but why do you think you need to hash it in the first place? What is wrong with N/P*60?

Comment: I don't think you can get an evenly distributed hascode (skew) from random strings,

Comment: @SectoKia I never mentioned length of strings. Yes, N/P*60 tells me how many jobs to execute per second, but it doesn't tell me _which_ job to execute when. How else would I do that without starting with a hash?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie If you can get a random distribution using `rand()`, I don't see why you can't get a random distribution using random strings.

Comment: To me, it is totally unclear what you want to achieve with your scheduler; which resource to optimize. Why not use time slicing?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I said in the original description that I want the jobs (that would otherwise all start at the same time) to be evenly distributed over their period, each with a deterministic skew. I'm not trying to optimize any resource. I'm trying to reduce the "burstiness" of job spawning so they don't all start at the zeroth second of every minute (for every-minute jobs) or, say, don't start all at the zeroth second of every fifth minute on the fives (for every-five-minute jobs).

Comment: They never all start at the zeroeth second because a CPU can handle only one process at a time. So they are all time-sliced sequenced. Otherwise make a batch scheduler that runs one job to completion at a time. With your "skew" you can leave idle time between a completed job and the next job scheduled. Again, I don't understand what you want to accomplish [that isn't already accomplished by the scheduler].

Comment: @PaulOgilvie There are multi-CPU machines. Regardless, I've described what I want as clearly as I can (including the _new_ examples). If it's still not clear to you, I respectfully request that you move on.